# Calling locally hosted server from an AWS Lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda

I have a REST API and have hosted it in my local box. The URL is
http://localhost:3000.

I have an AWS lambda function that has to call this local host to get some data for testing purposes. However, whenever I call this URL I am getting an UnknownHostException.

Is there any way to call this loaclhost from inside my AWS lambda function?

Comment: There is no "this localhost" -- `localhost` is a special hostname that refers to the *local* machine, no matter what machine that happens to be.  It never refers to a different machine, so trying to access `localhost` from elsewhere is, by definition, impossible... so it's a little bit unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

you can't access your localhost with a request from aws or anywhere else. host your api somewhere then you can make a request to it from lambda using:

```
 var url = yoursite.com:3000
 http.get(url, function(res) {
   console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
 }).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

if you want to host it locally then use a DDNS service.

Answer (score 0):

- Trying to access `localhost` from other devices/machines is not possible.
  AWS Lambda also can't do in that case.
- I would suggest you to **tunnel your localhost** using [localtunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel).
- You will get a randomly generated url for tunnel. Then you can call your REST from any other platforms.

Example:

```
//Install dependency
npm install -g localtunnel

//Start your local server
npm run dev

//Tunnel on the same port (Assuming that you run your REST on port 3000).
lt --port 3000

//Output:
>>> your url is: https://red-chairs-like-123-456-789-123.loca.lt
```

- So instead of sending request to `http://localhost:3000/users/profile`,
- you need to send your request to `https://red-chairs-like-123-456-789-123.loca.lt/users/profile`
- But make sure that everytime you make a change in REST code, or restart your server, you have to tunnel again.

**P.S.**

- I was having issue on my Android emulator, with sending requests to `http://localhost`. Android was rejecting sending request to unsecure `http`.
  I basically tunelled my localhost the same way to solve issue.